# I want to display all entries of 2D array in c++

Tags: c++

I want to create a program that take size of rows and columns of 2D array from user, and then take all entries of array from user. And Finally display all the entries from array[0][0] to array[size][size].

My code is:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int rows, columns;
    int tom[rows][columns];
    cout << "Size of array rows: ";
    cin >> rows;
    cout << "Size of array columns: ";
    cin >> columns;

    for(int count1 = 0; count1 < rows; count1++)
    {
        for(int count2 = 0; count2 < columns; count2++)
        {
            cout << "Enter entry of row " << count1 << " and column " << count2 << ": ";
            cin >> tom[count1][count2];
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
        {
            cout << tom[i][j] << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output is:

```
Size of array rows: 2
Size of array columns: 3
Enter entry of row 0 and column 0: 1
Enter entry of row 0 and column 1: 2
Enter entry of row 0 and column 2: 3
Enter entry of row 1 and column 0: 12
Enter entry of row 1 and column 1: 13
Enter entry of row 1 and column 2: 14
12
13
14
12
13
14
```

It should give output:

```
1
2
3
12
13
14
```

What is the problem?
Please help.

Comment: You were lucky (or unlucky). You should've gotten a seg-fault.

Comment: By the time your array is defined (`int tom[rows][coloumns];`), the values of `rows` and `coloumns` aren't.

Answer (score 2):

You can't dynamically create an array like this. This shouldn't even compile. And even if it did, you are creating the array *before* letting the user input the dimension. For the proper Approach use [`std::vector`](https://www.google.de/search?q=std%3A%3Avector&ie=&oe=):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    int rows, columns;
    std::cout << "Size of array rows: ";
    std::cin >> rows;
    std::cout << "Size of array columns: ";
    std::cin >> columns;
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> tom(rows, std::vector<int>(columns));

    for (int count1 = 0; count1 < rows; count1++)
    {
        for (int count2 = 0; count2 < columns; count2++)
        {
            std::cout << "Enter entry of row " << count1 << " and column " << count2 << ": ";
            std::cin >> tom[count1][count2];
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
        {
            std::cout << tom[i][j] << std::endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
Size of array rows: 2
Size of array columns: 3
Enter entry of row 0 and column 0: 1
Enter entry of row 0 and column 1: 2
Enter entry of row 0 and column 2: 3
Enter entry of row 1 and column 0: 12
Enter entry of row 1 and column 1: 13
Enter entry of row 1 and column 2: 14
1
2
3
12
13
14
```

---

please don't use `using namespace std;` - read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) why.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  **Your Words: **_You can't dynamically create an array like this. This shouldn't even compile. And even if it did, you are creating the array before letting the user input the dimension._ made my program. I just put the array `tom[rows][coloumns]` after the `cin >> coloumns;` and now it is working fine.

Comment: @AbdulRaheem what compiler are you using? this shouldn't really work unless there are some hidden _alloca() sort of hings going on.

Comment: Actually I'm at school level and I'm using dev cpp.

Comment: @AbdulRaheem i am saying it, because normally this doesn't work. `tom` wants to be a fixed-size array, allocated on the stack. you can't dynamically allocate an array on the stack. `E0028 expression must have a constant value` - you will have to make a dynamically allocated array - on the heap. this can be done with `int** tom` or with (the modern alternative) `std::vector<std::vector>>`. Your code might work for now, but once you run it else-where it will fail. It's just not a good practise to be stuck with These dependencies. When you want to improve, it's best to stick with good practises.

Comment: Okay sir. I'll be carefull next time. ☺

Comment: @StackDanny, *This shouldn't even compile.* --> eh! surprise surprise. "variable length arrays" (VLAs) are not part of standard C++, yes that is true. They were in C99, however. I know, I know this question is marked C++. Both `gcc` and `clang` compilers have implemented compiler-extensions, that allow VLAs. I don't know what `dev-cpp` uses as a compiler under the hood, but probably it is `mingw a.k.a. gcc`.

Comment: @JoeyMallone yes I heard of that and I have used dev-cpp before but I never thought that it would allow something like that! thanks for the Information.

Comment: @StackDanny, I knew gcc had that extension. I didn't know that clang also has that extension. It was surprising for me also, when it compiled on my system with both compilers.

Answer (score 1):

You initialized `tom` before actually getting the number of rows/columns.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int rows, columns;
    std::cout << "Rows: ";
    std::cin >> rows;
    std::cout << "Columns: ";
    std::cin >> columns;
    int arr[rows][columns];

    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
        {
            std::cout << "Enter the value for [" << i << "][" << j << "] : ";
            std::cin >> arr[i][j];
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
        {
            std::cout << arr[i][j] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: but i used `cin` to get the number of rows and columns.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot declare an array like this:

```
    int tom[rows][columns];
```

since values of rows and columns are not known yet.

Instead you should initialize this array dynamically after asking for values.
Here is your code fixed:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int rows, columns;
    int **tom;
    cout << "Size of array rows: ";
    cin >> rows;
    cout << "Size of array columns: ";
    cin >> columns;

    tom = new int*[rows];
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
      tom[i] = new int[columns];
    }

    for(int count1 = 0; count1 < rows; count1++)
    {
        for(int count2 = 0; count2 < columns; count2++)
        {
            cout << "Enter entry of row " << count1 << " and column " << count2 << ": ";
            cin >> tom[count1][count2];
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
        {
            cout << tom[i][j] << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: please just don't forget to `delete[]` the data afterwards.